# Connecting access database to silverlight project using WCF service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I'm currently still new in using Silverlight and WCF services in C#. I'm trying to write a silverlight app but I dont know how to connect a access database to the project i know you must use a WCF service to do so, but i'm stuck I was looking everywhere for help but cant find it. If anyone can help me it would be great.

Thanks 
Jacques Steyn

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/), which is a great start for connecting database to a Silverlight application (it uses WCF under the covers, but most of the details are hidden from the developer). The link above has a good description for the platform.